# Could not load QT platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: python, pyqt5, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I am trying to run a napari-based python program. I am getting the following error message

```
WARNING: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
01:04:11 WARNING:Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
WARNING: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

01:04:11 WARNING:This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not really sure what QT is and why it is causing these problems. I have tried installing QT5 directly from the website, but that did not resolve it either.

I have looked at old threads for these issues and they seem to have slightly different issues, and I am finding it difficult to apply their answers to mine.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am doing all of my work in a conda environment running Python3.

Comment: execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 your_command`

Comment: @eyllanesc I am getting a lot of different metadata for the various plugins such as linuxfb, eglfs, etc. Would I need to initialize one of these plugins? The last keys that are being retrieved from the list of metadata are the xcb keys. I am getting an expanded version of the xcb error: `Cannot load library ~/.../PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)` and `QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on .../platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library .../libqxcb.so: (cannot open shared object file: No such file"`

Comment: execute:  `sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0`

Comment: or better:  `sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev`